# Render a Markdown file stored in S3 uploaded with shrine - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, shrine

I'm using shrine to upload files from my rails application to S3. All is working fine, but I dont know how to display that file using redcarpet gem.

For example I can do this:

```
<div>
    <%= markdown("##title
    * ") %>
</div>
```

And works fine.

But if I do this:

```
<%= markdown(@rfile.rfile.url) %>
```

Is showing me a download link from S3.

How I can get the file content and not the file link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call to `@rfile.rfile` returns a `Shrine::UploadedFile` object, which has many more convenient methods other than just `#url`. On such method is `#read`, which retrieves content of the file:

```
<%= markdown(@rfile.rfile.read) %>
```

However, in this case the file would be opened and read, but not closed. So it's better to call `#open` with a block, and call `#read` on the yielded IO object, which can be neatly written as

```
<%= markdown(@rfile.rfile.open(&:read)) %>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error `incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8` in the footer, if I remove the footer it's works fine. I have to specify the encoding at some point?

Comment: nevermind I fixed it with this `<%= yield.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8) %>`Thanks!